# Weak topology and linear operators

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces an let $X_{w},Y_{w}$ denote the sames spaces with their weak topologies. Let $T : X\to Y$ be a bounded linear operator. Then the following operators are continuous: $T:X \to Y_{w}$, $T:X_{w} \to Y$ and $T: X_{w} \to Y_{w}$. I have $T:X \to Y_{w}$ and $T: X_{w} \to Y_{w}$ proved, how to prove $T:X_{w} \to Y$ is continuous?? i was trying by definition of weak topology, taking a basis but doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true. Take $X=Y$ and $T=I$ (the identity opoerator).  Then $T$ is a bounded operator but $T: X_w\to Y$ is not continuous unless $X$ is finite dimensional.